# gnu make findstring in argument containing path

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, gnu

I have a simple conditional (I need inline conditional statement):

```
$(if $(findstring foo,$1),yes,no)
```

If I print out $1 it can contain a path like:

```
../.././foo/bar/src/io
```

however, it does not evaluate to yes?
If I simply copy paste that path in instead of the variable(arg):

```
$(if $(findstring foo,../.././foo/bar/src/io),yes,no)
```

it evaluates yes.

Comment: There is no way this behavior can be explained unless you tell use where and how you are using this `$(if ...)` statement.  _Everything_ depends on what `$1` is and how this is used.  Is it used as part of a make `call`?  Is it used inside a recipe?  Etc.

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not "*evaluate to true*", it expands as `yes`.

```
$(findstring foo,../.././foo/bar/src/io)
```

expands as `foo` (because there is a match) and:

```
$(if foo,yes,no)
```

expands as `yes` (because `foo` is not the empty string). Compare with:

```
$(if $(findstring baz,../.././foo/bar/src/io),yes,no)
```

that expands as `no` because there is no match and:

```
$(findstring baz,../.././foo/bar/src/io)
```

expands as the empty string. Note that if the path is passed as a variable it does not change anything because the variable is expanded first:

```
$ cat Makefile
define MACRO
$(if $(findstring foo,$1),yes,no)
endef

$(info foo: $(call MACRO,../.././foo/bar/src/io))
$(info baz: $(call MACRO,../.././baz/bar/src/io))

.PHONY: all
all:;
$ make
foo: yes
baz: no
make: 'all' is up to date.
```